# Joining WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS to a Bill Of Materials table

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have an SQL query in which I am trying to fetch items along with their components which have Bill Of Materials (BOM) enabled and whose creation date is withing the last three years.
The problem is every item along with their component list gets repeated. Suppose an item has 5 components, and I query with the particular item number. I get 35 rows (7 repetitions of sets of 5 components). However, if I query with a particular WIP_ENTITY_NAME or if I use DISTINCT, I get a perfect 5 rows of data. I need to get this data (5 rows, no repetitions) when I query with a particular item number.
Here is the query:

```
SELECT *
FROM BOM_BILL_OF_MATERIALS BOM,
  BOM_INVENTORY_COMPONENTS BIC,
  BOM_COMPONENTS_B BCB,
  BOM_OPERATIONAL_ROUTINGS_V BORV,
  BOM_OPERATION_SEQUENCES_V BOSV,
  BOM_STRUCTURES_B BSB,
  BOM_STRUCTURE_TYPES_B BST,
  MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B MSI,
  MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_TL MSIT,
  ORG_ORGANIZATION_DEFINITIONS OOD,
  WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS_V WDJV
WHERE BOM.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID    = BIC.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID
AND BIC.COMPONENT_SEQUENCE_ID = BCB.COMPONENT_SEQUENCE_ID
AND BCB.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID      = BSB.BILL_SEQUENCE_ID
AND BOM.STRUCTURE_TYPE_ID     = BST.STRUCTURE_TYPE_ID
AND BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID     = MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID      = MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND BOSV.ROUTING_SEQUENCE_ID = BORV.ROUTING_SEQUENCE_ID
AND BORV.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID    = BOM.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID
AND BORV.ORGANIZATION_ID     = BOM.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID    = MSIT.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID
AND MSI.ORGANIZATION_ID      = MSIT.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSIT.ORGANIZATION_ID     = OOD.ORGANIZATION_ID
AND MSIT.LANGUAGE            = USERENV('LANG')
AND sysdate BETWEEN BCB.EFFECTIVITY_DATE AND NVL(BCB.DISABLE_DATE, sysdate)
AND MSI.BOM_ENABLED_FLAG            = 'Y'
AND NVL(MSI.ENABLED_FLAG,'X')       ='Y'
AND OOD.ORGANIZATION_ID            IN (203,204,328)
AND BORV.COMMON_ROUTING_SEQUENCE_ID = WDJV.COMMON_ROUTING_SEQUENCE_ID
AND BORV.ASSEMBLY_ITEM_ID = WDJV.PRIMARY_ITEM_ID
AND WDJV.CREATION_DATE    > ADD_MONTHS( sysdate, -12*3 )
AND WDJV.WIP_ENTITY_NAME = '28799'
  --and MSI.SEGMENT1='9064090'
```

Also, I have found that the sets of 5 differ from each other on the basis of their WE_ROW_ID, REQUEST_ID_7, SCHEDULED_START_DATE, SCHEDULED_COMPLETION_DATE and other columns which are present in the WIP_DISCREET_JOBS table. Is there any way to map these columns to any of the BOM tables? I am new to this, so please bear with me gurus.

Comment: Please have a look at [mcve] to improve your question. Besides, the old Oracle join syntax is not a great idea; consider using ANSI sql

Comment: @Aleksej Considering ANSI SQL isn't in my hands. I have to use this syntax.

Comment: @SoumyadeepPaul You could still follow Aleksej's other suggestion by removing irrelevant tables, joins, filters and selected columns from this query until it is about 10-15 lines long rather than 40.  Presumably all those outer joined lookups aren't the cause of the issue anyway?  If not, remove them from the query and re-post.  That will help us to help you!

Comment: @TonyAndrews These tables are used in the Joins, so I presume they're necessary. Also, following your suggestion, I have removed the Joins having the lookups, and the output is still the same.

Comment: Yes, they are necessary to your business, but they are not relevant to solving the problem, which is what you are asking us to do.  In your test SQL, keep removing these tables, joins, filters and selected columns until you have the smallest possible SQL statement that still exhibits the problem.  Then maybe we can "see the wood for the trees".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see you are asking about the Oracle e-Business Suite data model.

> > trying to fetch items ... and whose creation date is withing the last three years.

That is not what your query is doing.  You are getting details of items made (via a WIP discrete job) within the last 3 years -- and you are getting a duplicate of the item for every time it was made (i.e., every occurrence in `WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS_V`).

If you want items made in the last 3 years, but you only want each item once, you should use an `EXISTS` (semi-join) to filter the rows instead of actually joining to `WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS_V`, which will cause duplicates).  Something more along these lines:

```
SELECT *
FROM   bom_bill_of_materials bom,
       bom_inventory_components bic,
       bom_components_b bcb,
       bom_operational_routings_v borv,
       bom_operation_sequences_v bosv,
       bom_structures_b bsb,
       bom_structure_types_b bst,
       mtl_system_items_b msi,
       mtl_system_items_tl msit,
       org_organization_definitions ood --,
       --wip_discrete_jobs_v wdjv
WHERE  bom.bill_sequence_id = bic.bill_sequence_id
AND    bic.component_sequence_id = bcb.component_sequence_id
AND    bcb.bill_sequence_id = bsb.bill_sequence_id
AND    bom.structure_type_id = bst.structure_type_id
AND    bom.assembly_item_id = msi.inventory_item_id
AND    bom.organization_id = msi.organization_id
AND    bosv.routing_sequence_id = borv.routing_sequence_id
AND    borv.assembly_item_id = bom.assembly_item_id
AND    borv.organization_id = bom.organization_id
AND    msi.inventory_item_id = msit.inventory_item_id
AND    msi.organization_id = msit.organization_id
AND    msit.organization_id = ood.organization_id
AND    msit.language = USERENV ('LANG')
AND    SYSDATE BETWEEN bcb.effectivity_date AND NVL (bcb.disable_date, SYSDATE)
AND    msi.bom_enabled_flag = 'Y'
AND    NVL (msi.enabled_flag, 'X') = 'Y'
AND    ood.organization_id IN (203, 204, 328)
--AND    borv.common_routing_sequence_id = wdjv.common_routing_sequence_id
--AND    borv.assembly_item_id = wdjv.primary_item_id
--AND    wdjv.creation_date > ADD_MONTHS (SYSDATE, -12 * 3)
--AND    wdjv.wip_entity_name = '28799'
AND    EXISTS ( SELECT 'discrete job within the last 3 years'
                FROM   wip_discrete_jobs_v wdjv
                WHERE  wdjv.common_routing_sequence_id = borv.common_routing_sequence_id
                AND    wdjv.primary_item_id = borv.assembly_item_id
                AND    wdjv.creation_date >= ADD_MONTHS(SYSDATE, -12*3)
                )
--and MSI.SEGMENT1='9064090'
```

Note -- I kept this as close to your original query as possible and I didn't verify all the join conditions you used.  So there may be some other bugs in your initial query that I have inadvertently duplicated.

One other thing, it's not a good practice to use the forms views, like `WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS_V` or `BOM_OPERATIONAL_ROUTINGS_V`.  These views are to provide data to online forms.  Not only can your performance suffer (because they contain joins that you may not need), but, if you go to Oracle's eTRM site (http://etrm.oracle.com/pls/etrm/etrm_pnav.show_object?c_name=BOM_OPERATIONAL_ROUTINGS_V&c_owner=APPS&c_type=VIEW), you will see this warning:

> Warning: Oracle does not recommend you query or alter datausing this
>   view. It may change dramatically in subsequent minor or major
>   releases.

It is better to `SELECT` from the base tables.

Comment: Your query works flawlessly. But you also mentioned that "if I only want each item once, I should use an EXISTS (semi-join) to filter the rows instead of actually joining to WIP_DISCRETE_JOBS_V." Can you explain a bit more, please?
Also, I understand the long-term effects of using the form views and have replaced the view tables with the base tables following your suggestion. Thanks, again.

Comment: The query I gave you was an example of how you would use an `EXISTS` / semi-join to filter your items.  `EXISTS` is just an expression that returns `TRUE` if the (usually correlated) subquery returns any rows.  See https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/queries006.htm#SQLRF30046

Comment: Even though I do get unique records, I still can't seem to fetch all the components for each item. I am trying to select COMPONENT_ITEM_ID from BOM_INVENTORY_COMPONENTS. I joined this column to the INVENTORY_ITEM_ID of MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS_B table. Either it returns Null or incomplete data for each item.

Comment: That's the correct join more-or-less (you also need to limit `MTL_SYSTEM_ITEMS.ORGANIZATION_ID` somehow).  I don't know what's `null` or "incomplete".  I recommend you post your query and latest problem in a separate question.

Comment: I have posted the latest query in a separate topic. Can you please have a look into it?